# How to display selected listbox text in a texbox? Word 2016 VB

Tags: vba, ms-word

First, let me say I am new to VB and really all Code. I'm trying to make 
a simple listbox selection show in a textbox from a button push. I've 
found some code that looked like it worked, but only populates the first 
item entered into my listbox, no matter what has been selected in that 
Listbox. I am missing something!

Most of what I've found online is saying to use a SelectedItem or Get? 
but I just get an error on those.

[UserForm Image Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccamz.png)

```
   Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
        UserForm1.TextBox1 = ListBox1.List(lItem)

End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim myArray() As String
          'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array.
           myArray = Split(".020|.030|.032|", "|")
           'Use .List method to populate listbox.
        ListBox1.List = myArray
lbl_Exit:


    'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array.
          myArray = Split("THK|DIA|TUBE|FORGING", "|")
    'Use .List method to populate listbox.
     ListBox2.List = myArray


     'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array.
          myArray = Split("INCO|CRES|", "|")
     'Use .List method to populate listbox.
          ListBox3.List = myArray

    'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array.
          myArray = Split("625|304|5052|", "|")
    'Use .List method to populate listbox.
          ListBox4.List = myArray


     'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array.
          myArray = Split("AMS 5599|AMS 5512|AMS 4117|", "|")
     'Use .List method to populate listbox.
          ComboBox1.List = myArray

    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        TextBox4.Visible = False
        TextBox5.Visible = False
        Label10.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = False
        Label11.Visible = False
        Label8.Visible = False
        Label9.Visible = False
        CommandButton1.Visible = True
        CommandButton6.Visible = False
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get, and on which line?

Comment: With the code that I posted I don,t get an error, but my text box will only show the first item added to my list box.

Comment: TextBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem ---If I try anything like .SelectedItem or .Value They are the Highlighted errors (Compile error: Method or Data not found) So ,I think I'm missing something

Comment: what's `lItem` in the second line of your code?

Comment: That was just a part of the code I was copying as I was trying to piece this userform together. If I remove it I don't even get the first Item in my listbox1 to show in the textbox1